# Beamer latex presentation slide in bullets and then finally comes a block in over all bullets and dim the bullets

Tags: beamer

[image]I would like to make a beamer slide in which there are bullets which I know how to do..
But then i want to add a block over all the bullets and dim the bullets.

Like bullets text got dimmed and this block appears in end of slide covering bullets.

Comment: Will your itemize have subitems? This would change things... Please give a simple example of what you already have with bullets and be more specific about the block you want on last frame (I suppose there)

Comment: Can you clarify the terminology? What is a "block" in this case? And by "dim" you mean render the bullet transparant?

Comment: Can you please make a sketch how the result should look like? Do you mean a beamer block or just a simple boarder around the items? What do you mean with dim? Transparent? Changing the colour?

Comment: Kindly have a look over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "dim" the bullets, you can cover them again using overlay specifications. To add a big rectangle on top of the content, a quick way is to use a `picture` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{%
still covered={\opaqueness<1>{15}\opaqueness<2>{10}\opaqueness<3>{5}\opaqueness<4->{2}},
again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1> test
    \item<1> test
    \end{itemize}
    \only<2>{
   \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(50,0){\color{blue}\rule{.6\textwidth}{.3\textheight}}
            \put(110,30){question block}
    \end{picture}

   }%
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot.. This is what I was looking for.. Many thanks